# Am I voting too much?

Tags: discussion, voting

If you ask a question that I can understand what you want to know, if you answer something that is not *bad* advice I will upvote you.

When this site was SE1.0 I voted my mouse off to get the strangers excited and wanting to stick around.

Sometimes, if my vote does not change the order of the answers (like the top one has 5 and the next one has 2) I vote for the answer even when I disagree but see the point.  I have hit the vote cap several times, but not daily.

Does this pollute the site, or do you think I am in fact encouraging people to be around participate?  Does the SE system think I am spamming votes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is OK and even encouraged, so long as you are only voting up *things you honestly believe to be useful.*

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/

I would also pay special attention to this page to "welcome" your new quality users:

https://money.stackexchange.com/review

Comment: Hey look at that page.  Cool.  Didn't know it existed.

Comment: Is there a link to get to the review page, other than just typing it in the URL? I was unaware of this as well.

Answer (score 7):

I think your voting habits are great, as long as you are also willing to downvote *harmful* questions and answers, and vote to close the things that don't belong.

Comment: Yes, I do down vote junk and vote to close.